# How do I make this pythag theorem work?

Tags: python

Define a function `hypotenuse(a, b)` which returns the length of the hypotenuse `c`, if the other two sides have lengths `a` and `b`.

```
import math
def hypotenuse(a, b):
   print(b = (math.sqrt((a**2)-(b**2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def hypotenuse(a, b):
    return math.sqrt((a**2) + (b**2))   # ... SUM of the squares ...
```

But since you're importing `math`, why not

```
def hypotenuse(a, b)
    return math.hypot(a, b)
```

Comment: This works, of course, but you fixed his two most serious problems without any explanation, but explained the simplest one…

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you can't assign variables in an expression in Python.

I'm not sure why you want to reassign `b` this way in the first place. But if you want to, you have to move it to its own statement. (While we're at it, I'll remove the two layers of excess parens and add some spaces to make it more readable.)

```
b = math.sqrt(a**2 - b**2)
print(b)
```

If you *don't* want to (since you're not doing anything with it anyway), just don't do it:

```
print(math.sqrt(a**2 - b**2))
```

---

The second problem is that you're not actually `return`ing anything, just `print`ing something out. If you fall off the end of a function without a `return` statement, you return `None`. So, change it to this:

```
return math.sqrt(a**2 - b**2)
```

---

And your third problem, as gnibbler explained, is that you've got the algorithm wrong. The square of the hypotenuse is the *sum* of the squares, not the *difference*. So:

```
return math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
```